# UITableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath is not getting called after low memory warning

Tags: iphone, uitableview, low-memory

I am new to COCOA and Objective C. I am working on an application which have two controllers with one table view in each, clicking an item form this table will lead to another controller to be pushed to the stack. All was working fine till i started handling low memory warning in app delegate. What i am doing in app delegate's applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning is, deleting all of my model and popping out all controllers to its root view using popToRootViewControllerAnimated.

Now my problem starts, once low mem warning is received table's cellForRowAtIndexPath is not getting called. All other methods of UITableViewDataSource is properly called. What i get on screen is a blank white screen. I am testing my app in iPhone OS 3.0 and development is done in Xcode V 3.1.3. 
Hope you guys can help me to nail this.

Thanks in advance, Jinesh.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Release the all abject like images, scroll view  at the method

```
-(void)didreceivememoryWarning
{
[super didreceivememorywarning];
}
```